# The New Mega-Splitter™: What's Next?

Tags: pattern

Here we have the great pyramid. The brand new 50-50, Out-to-In Mega-Splitter™.

[image: mega-splitter]

Fill in the question marks with the next numbers!

<sub><sup>*All the hints you should need are in the question!*</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> | 4 | 38 | 154 | 302 | 364 | 302 | 154 | 38 | 4 |

> This is because as I observed, starting with the first box (top), a box splits into 3 with | half | whole | half | of the number.

> For boxes with overlapping numbers, they are just added. For example, box |32| splits into |16|32|16|, but the final |16| has a |64| from the splitting of |64|, and another |16| from the other |32|.

> I also have noticed that this pyramid is mirrored, so I only solved half of it (including the middle box).

Comment: There seems to be a hole in your logic here for example, 16 and 40 according to you makes 56 in the fourth column, but it doesnt, it makes 60.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker -- I believe you may be right! Once I finish checking it over, (probably tomorrow; it's quite late where I live right now) I will fix that!

Comment: Oh, I may have to redo my answer after this... Thank you! I w I